# Why are collection navigation properties not initialized for lazy loading proxy classes

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, poco

In one of my projects I use Entity Framework with virtual navigation properties on the entities. This means the entities are loaded from the database or created with `IDbSet<T>.Create()` a DynamicProxy is returned. Because I only make navigation properties virtual, this proxy does lazy loading and no change tracking (all properties need to be `virtual` to get a change tracking proxy).

My assumption was that the DynamicProxy takes care of initializing virtual `ICollection<T>` properties, as it does when the entity is loaded from the database. But when I create a new entity using `IDbSet<T>.Create()`, these navigation properties remain `null`.

Then I tried to make all properties `virtual` so I get a DynamicProxy with change tracking and to my surprise these navigation properties are initialized.

See the following example:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Data.Entity;

static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        using (var db = new BloggingContext())
        {
            var changeTrackingBlog = db.ChangeTrackingBlogs
                                       .Create(); // returns a DynamicProxy
            var changeTrackingBlogPostCount = changeTrackingBlog
                              .Posts
                              .Count; // Posts has type EntityCollection<Post>

            var lazyLoadingBlog = db.LazyLoadingBlogs
                                    .Create(); // returns a DynamicProxy
            var lazyLoadingBlogPostCount = lazyLoadingBlog.Posts
                                                .Count; // Posts == null
        } 
    }
}

public class BloggingContext : DbContext
{
    public IDbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    public IDbSet<ChangeTrackingBlog> ChangeTrackingBlogs { get; set; }
    public IDbSet<LazyLoadingBlog> LazyLoadingBlogs { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    [Key]
    public int PostId { get; set; }

    public virtual ChangeTrackingBlog ChangeTrackingBlog { get; set; }
    public virtual LazyLoadingBlog LazyLoadingBlog { get; set; }
}

public class ChangeTrackingBlog
{
    [Key]
    public virtual int BlogId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

public class LazyLoadingBlog
{
    // Not all properties are virtual, so no Change tracking, just lazy loading
    [Key]
    public int BlogId { get; set; } 

    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}
```

I hope someone can explain what's happening here.

Comment: Are you wure that those collection navigation properties are initialized when you make all the properties virtual, allowing to create a change tracking proxy? I think you're wrong. These collection properties are only automatically instanced when you use lazy loading, and access them. If not, they're still null.

Comment: @JotaBe: Good point, but the `Posts` property is initialized before being accessed in case of the change tracking proxy.

Comment: That's what I meant: always initialize collection properties unless you load it via lazy loading, or you'll get a "null reference exception". AFAIK collection properties are never initialized unless they re lazy, eagerly or explicitly loaded. Putting it in your class constructor will not make any interference.

Answer (score 2):

The usual way to avoid the null reference is to initialize the collection in the constructor:

```
public LazyLoading()
{
   Posts = new List();
}
```

I believe it may be better practise to use a backing field - something to do with anonymous constructors not being called in certain circumstances (serialization or something - apologies for vagueness). So I do this:

```
public class LazyLoadingBlog
{
    private ICollection<Post> _Posts = new List<Post>();

    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts 
    { 
       get { return _Posts ; }
       //protected set lets EF override for lazy loading
       protected set { _Posts = value; 
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I can't explain why you don't get an error when you mark all the properties virtual...

Comment: Thanks! Initializing the properties in the constructor means accessing a virtual member from a constructor, this can lead to other issues, so I don't like that solution.
I guess I could change the automatic properties to properties with a backing field.
Still I like to know why there's a difference :)

Comment: I think that's actually the main reason I went with the backing field - I was getting a warning from CodeRush because of the virtual call. And yes, I'd like to know the difference too

Comment: I tested initializing the collection in the constructor. This doesn't work for proxies with change tracking, because it throws an `InvalidOperationException`: Additional information: The property 'Posts' on type 'ChangeTrackingBlog_E2538CFF8F25D3B52885F4D5A327D1183626232C1097A36B54E666D62E02C6FD' cannot be set because the collection is already set to an EntityCollection.
I think you're right, creating properties with a backing field is the only solution for this problem.